# Proper implementation of Repository Pattern with MVVM in WPF

Tags: mvvm, repository-pattern, unit-of-work

I am currently refactoring a WPF application that is built on the principles of the `Repository Pattern`. It uses `Entity Framework` as its ORM, and is Database First. Each of those entities is wrapped by `Repository`, the interfaces of which are then used in `Unit Of Work`. Those units of work are then used by `ViewModels`.

However, a single transaction like, say, `CreateInvoice()` affects several tables. For example, `CreateInvoice()` would insert a `Sale` record in `Sales` Table, deduct available stock in `Stock` Table, and so on and so forth. Here is a sample code for that:

```
public void Commit(IContainInvoiceInfo InvoiceInfo)
{
    _invoiceInfo = InvoiceInfo;

    try
    {
        _uow.BeginTransaction();
        InsertInSalesTable();
        UpdateCurrentStock();
        UpdatePacketStock();
        InsertStockHistoryEntries();
        InsertInTaxTable();
        _uow.Complete();
        _uow.EndTransaction();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        _uow.RollBack();
        throw ex;
    }
}

private void InsertInSalesTable()
{
    _uow.salesrepo.Add(new Sale
    {
        ID = _invoiceInfo.InvoiceNum.ToString(),
        client = _invoiceInfo.SelectedClient.ID,
        saledate = _invoiceInfo.InvoiceDate,
        totalvalue = _invoiceInfo.GrandTotal,
        purchaseorder = string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(_invoiceInfo.PONumber) ? null : _invoiceInfo.PONumber + "dated: " + _invoiceInfo.PODate.ToString("dd-MM-yy")
    });
}
...
```

So, basically, ViewModels are doing the heavy-lifting of properly inserting data into the proper tables in a database.

The problem is that since I am using Entity Framework `DB First` approach, the model generated is an anaemic one. They are simple data classes with absolutely no behaviour.

I could encapsulate this logic in the `Unit Of Work` itself, or even create stored procedure in the database itself, or create a separate service layer which would consume the Units of Work and then make the ViewModels use the services instead of the Units of Work.

Which is the correct place to encapsulate this insertion/update logic?

Comment: Are you not using databinding at all? The "heavy lifting" looks like, from the code sample, as something that is mostly automated by bindings.

Comment: I am using databinding. In fact, I am using `Caliburn.Micro` for that purpose

Comment: I should have been a bit clear, perhaps. Let's say, there's a view where users can create an invoice. So, based on that invoice information, records need to be saved/updated into the Sales Table and Stock Table of the database. Now, the ViewModel uses the SalesUnitOfWork to update the respective tables. However, this means that ViewModel is quite aware of the Database Schema. Is there any way to make the ViewModel absolutely Database-agnostic?

Comment: You can always move your business logic from the app to the database or separate .dll if that would make you more comfortable... That would, however, render ORM and/or MVVM mostly inapplicable. Which is place better would depend on your situation. I was just pointinting out that `InsertInSalesTable` should probably never existed in the first place if you used bidnings, because you would have a `Sale` object bound and filled from UI optionally inserted in an EF-backed collection through a `ICommand` ~your `Commit`.

Comment: So you're probably talking about facade pattern. I am not using that, unfortunately. The view has textboxes and comboboxes that are simply bound to `string` and `ObservableCollection` (`BindableCollection` because I'm using Caliburn). Creating a Sales object from those input data is done inside the `ICommand`.

Comment: `The problem is that since I am using Entity Framework DB First approach, the model generated is an anaemic one. They are simple data classes with absolutely no behaviour.` -- Yes, that's how this works.  Why is it a problem?

Comment: `Is there any way to make the ViewModel absolutely Database-agnostic?` -- add an indirection layer that has a collection API on one side and your EF stuff on the other side.  Your database can interact with the database API; your ViewModel can interact with the collections API.  Provide methods on the collections side so that the ViewModel can ask for the data that it wants.

Comment: Anaemic Domain Models are usually looked down upon. I was actually thinking of using a separate business layer with all this logic. Another way of tackling this is to use Stored Procedures in the Database itself, although it comes with a hit in modifiability of database.
`Provide methods on the collections side so that the ViewModel can ask for the data that it wants.` This is probably the best recourse.

Comment: @MycroftHolmes `However, this means that ViewModel is quite aware of the Database Schema.` Not if you use DTOs, which you should.